# C#: Why didn't Microsoft make a ReadOnlyCollection<T> inherit from the ReadOnlyCollectionBase?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

Simply put, Microsoft defined a `ReadOnlyCollectionBase`, yet did not use it as the base class for `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` when it clearly sounds that this should have been the way.

Am I missing something here? I mean, was there a good reason to **NOT** make this class the base class?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably because it's not generic and implements `ICollection` whereas `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is generic and implements `ICollection<T>`. Note that `ICollection<T>` does not implement `ICollection`. On that [topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2005/09/23/Collections.aspx):

> `ICollection<T>` seems like `ICollection`, but it’s actually a very different abstraction. We found that `ICollection` was not very useful. At the same time, we did not have an abstraction that represented an read/write non-indexed collection. `ICollection<T>` is such abstraction and you could say that `ICollection` does not have an exact corresponding peer in the generic world; `IEnumerable<T>` is the closest.

From that same post:

> `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is a much better `ReadOnlyCollectionBase`. It’s in `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace.

Effectively, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is `ReadOnlyCollectionBase` in the generics space.

Note, similarly, that `IList<T>` does not implement `IList`.

In general, pre-generics classes do not serve as useful abstractions for generic classes (with the exception of `IEnumerable`).

Comment: Really, `IEnumerable` has the same issue as `IList` in principle, but implementing a single extra method (and a single extra property on the enumerator) was not considered a burden, compared to the dozens you would need for `IList` (which `List<T>` and indeed `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` do implement, separately from their generic collection interfaces)

Comment: Any idea why `IList<T>` doesn't inherit from `ICollection`?  Since the latter is basically `IEnumerable` plus `Count`, and since `IList<T>` already has a `Count` method, having `IList<T>` inherit `ICollection` wouldn't have required any more work for implementers, but would have allowed someone with an `IList<anything>` to know how many items to expect from an enumeration.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the history of the .net framework, you'll find generics since 2.0, but `ReadOnlyCollectionBase` already in 1.1. The reason for not choosing `ReadOnlyCollectionBase` is simple - it isn't generic, while the aim of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is to be generic. Thus it needs a much different inheritance tree.

The purpose for all the `*CollectionBase` classes was to provide a foundation for implementing strongly typed collections in .net 1.1. With the introduction of generics in 2.0, they became obsolete, however are still in the framework for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

If they did it would probably be a violation of [Liskov's Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from a non-generic base class would be ineffecient. If the type was using a non-generic base, all it would be would be a thin layer above the base collection, where the generic features would simply derive from casting from the underlying `object` instances of the base collection.

This causes unnecessary boxing/unboxing of value types. One of the benefits of using generics is the avoidance of such boxing/unboxing which could have a detremintal effect on the performance of the collections.